# MVC Home Controller debugging unsuccesfull

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am able to remote debug, and when I trace it , it goes thru all other cs files like HttpApplication.cs

I can debug and it hits till in ..\Website\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml, since this has a delay I waited and the debugger timed out.

```
 $("#pageSearchField").autocomplete({
            delay: 500,
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetSuggestionList", "Home")',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: request,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
```

But it doesn’t go further, I also put break point in ..\Website\Controllers\HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult GetSuggestionList(string term){
//break point here
        int numberOfResults;
        int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NumberOfResults"], out numberOfResults);

        var matched = _repository.GetSearchGroupList(term.ToLower(), numberOfResults);

        return Json(matched, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I am also including routing

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the URL routes with the underlying MVC framework.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="routes">The route collection to which the routes will be added.</param>
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be helpful and appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you run it locally? What is the **rendered** value of `Url.Action("GetSuggestionList", "Home")`?

Comment: BTW, you have a bug where your code will return no results if `TryParse` is unsuccessful. You should fall-back to a default page size or return an error response.

Comment: Is there any error message in console log?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank everyone taking time and reading and trying to solve this problem. I did 2 things and got resolved.
[Enable Microsoft Symbol Servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92iT8.jpg)

and after that copied all the build files from the dev machine to remote machine and replaced it where the files were.

Thanks